# Neo4j AND clause

Tags: neo4j, cypher

New to Neo4j and looking for AND clause in a Cypher query.
Suppose I have Person nodes and Role nodes. A person can have multiple Roles (Manager, Leader, IC, QA,...) 
I want to find the set of People who have both the roles of Manager and QA.

Somethng like:
MATCH (p:Person)-[:HAS_ROLE]->(r:Role{name:"Manager"}) AND (p)-[:HAS_ROLE]->(r:Role{name:"QA"}) 
RETURN p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[:HAS_ROLE]->(:Role{name:"Manager"})
WHERE (p)-[:HAS_ROLE]->(:Role{name:"QA"})
RETURN p
```

this above query can be used if its just two Roles.But if want try for Many,then

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[:HAS_ROLE]->(r:Role)
WITH p, COLLECT(r.name) as roles
WHERE ALL (x IN ["Manager","QA"] WHERE x IN roles)
RETURN p
```

you can update this `["Manager","QA"]` with all the roles you want to check for a person.

Comment: Thanks for both your answers!
I tried your answer but didn't get any results for the Many case. Then realized that the roles collection was limited to just "Manager" and so it wasn't possible to also match "QA" in the where clause. A slight change to
MATCH (p:Person)-[:HAS_ROLE]->(r:Role)
WITH p, COLLECT(r.name) as roles
WHERE ALL (x IN ["Manager","QA"] WHERE x IN roles)
RETURN p
And it works! Thank again!

Answer (score 0):

You use r twice

Try :Role instead of r:Role

Comment: You're right, having r defined twice was a mistake in my query. Thanks!